# How to tell if you have been converted to Universal Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Just sitting down to look at this.  The FAQs state:

"There are two components that could be using either classic Google Analytics or Universal Analytics: 1) an account property and 2) the tracking code implemented on a website, mobile app, or other digital device.

Check both components to find out if you’re partially or completely using Universal Analytics."|

What would distinguish the old from the new?  Here are the setAccount and a trackEvent tag in place right now.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', UA-00000000-0']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'SiteUserProfile','UserID','000000',000000,true]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's using the classic analytics tracking code, i.e. [ga.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/). The new tracking code, [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/), looks like this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Note that at the moment, ga.js code can send hits to a Universal Analytics enabled property.